# show this inequaliy $\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{|b-c|}\ge 3$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

let $a,b,c,d,e\ge 0$ be different numbers, show that 
$$\dfrac{a}{|b-c|}+\dfrac{b}{|c-d|}+\dfrac{c}{|d-e|}+\dfrac{d}{|e-a|}+\dfrac{e}{|a-b|}\ge 3.$$

It seem like Shapiro's inequality $n=5$ case ? [Prove of Nesbitt's inequality in 6 variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921593/prove-of-nesbitts-inequality-in-6-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1)
But I can't use this reslut to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $e=\min\{a,b,c,d,e\}$.

Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{|b-c|}=\frac{a}{|b-c|}+\frac{b}{|c-d|}+\frac{c}{d-e}+\frac{d}{a-e}+\frac{e}{|a-b|}\geq$$
$$\geq \frac{a}{|b-c|}+\frac{b}{|c-d|}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}.$$
Now, let $c=\min\{b,c,d\}$.

Thus, by AM-GM $$\frac{a}{|b-c|}+\frac{b}{|c-d|}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}=\frac{a}{b-c}+\frac{b}{d-c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}\geq\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{d}+\frac{d}{a}\geq3.$$

Let $b=\min\{b,c,d\}$.

Thus, by AM-GM again: $$\frac{a}{|b-c|}+\frac{b}{|c-d|}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}=\frac{a}{c-b}+\frac{b}{|c-d|}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}\geq\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}\geq3.$$
Let $d=\min\{b,c,d\}$.

This case for you.

Comment: Nice !+1 Thanks,and I guess for $2n-1$ it's $n$,But I can't prove it

Comment: @inequality You are welcome!